# Microsoft word citation format issue

Tags: microsoft-word

I have created a list of sources to use as a citation, but when I insert it in my word file, it appears in a weird way:
[image: inserted citation]
[image: source list]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view the citation, right click on the citation, then select `Toggle Field Codes`.

Comment: thanks, it works

Comment: Or press Alt+F9